# Problems on an activitygroup under tabshost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm developing an application that have an activity Group inside a tabhost., so i have working s stack of activities inside the same tab.

The problem emerges when i try the search interface and inside this tab and nothing happens, if I launch the search Interface in another activity works normally".

Also, if I try to to execute a method from the layout xml with the "onClick" option the  app crashes

```
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40538fa0 is not valid; is your activity running?
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:562)
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.show(DatePickerDialog.java:132)
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2727)
01-06 10:09:24.533: E/AndroidRuntime(1404):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2685)
```

I also noted that if i intent to display  a dialog inside this ActivityGroup crashes, but i overlap this issue getting the the context of the parent activity to display it.

```
m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Please wait", "Downloading info", true,false);
```

instead

```
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait", "Downloading info", true,false);
```

It could something to have a nested class?

Greetings

Comment: So many questions at the end I  am not clear what you are looking for. Please clarify your issue. Yes, when it comes to Tabhost, while displaying Dialogs you need to use getParent() instead of this because Dialog window inflates the total app.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_id);
```

which causes the COntext Problems in the ActivityGroup.

Try using it this way:

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.your_id, null);
setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

And as a short note: You should maybe switch to fragments, because ActivityGroups are deprecated. They make a lot of trouble ...

Answer (score 0):

do

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.your_id, null);
setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

Remove the onClick method in the xml file and put a onClickListener on the button in java code. This will do the job ;)